# How much data can be stored in network buffer when datareader is used

Tags: c#, datareader

all we know that datareader works like

The datareader reads a record at a time, but it reads it from the underlying database driver. The database driver reads data from the database in blocks, typically using a buffer that is 8 kilobytes.

If your result records are small and you don't get very many, they will all fit in the buffer, and the database driver will be able to feed them all to the data reader without having to ask the database for more data.

If you fetch a result that is larger than the buffer, you will only be able to read the first part of it and when there will no data exist in network buffer then datareader will inform sql server to send next block of data.

### here is small code how we use data reader

```
String selectString = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCT";  
    IList<client> clients = new List<client>();  
    using (var selectCommand = new OracleCommand(connection, selectString))  
    {  
        using (OracleDataReader selectReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader())  
        {   
           if (selectReader.HasRows)  
           {  
               while (selectReader.Read())  
               {  
                   clientes.add( GetDomainObject(selectReader) );  
               }  
               selectReader.close();  
           }  
        }
    }
```

suppose PRODUCT table has 10,000 records. so i like to know how much data can accommodate in network buffer at a time?

because when `datareader.ExecuteReader()` will call then reader will fetch a block of data and stored in network buffer in that pc. when `datareader.read()` will call then single data will be forwarded to reader from buffer. when all read wil be read from buffer then a database call will made again and next block of data will be stored in buffer.

i am just curious to know how much data a data reader can stored in buffer when data fetch from db.
data reader will always fetch a fixed number of rows from db & stored in buffer or does it depend on buffer size?

buffer size depend on what....does it depend on ram ?

please discuss only the network buffer related things because i know how data reader works. thanks

Comment: network buffering is unlikely to be a bottleneck....

Comment: And buffer size doesn't depend on available RAM. It's just a convenient value to prevent extreme inefficiency in operations (ie. sending data one byte at a time). Stop guessing, test and profile. If you want to see what packets are being exchanged between the client and the server, use Wireshark or another packet sniffer. If you believe it might be a performance bottleneck, stop believing and test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your setup have a read of this [Default Result Set Processing and Multiple Active Result Sets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187602.aspx) and [Rowsets and SQL Server Cursors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130840.aspx)

Look into [TcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.receivebuffersize%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) it will tell you how much raw data can be read in one operation.

"The ReceiveBufferSize property gets or sets the number of bytes that you are expecting to store in the receive buffer for each read operation. This property actually manipulates the network buffer space allocated for receiving incoming data.

Your network buffer should be at least as large as your application buffer to ensure that the desired data will be available when you call the NetworkStream.Read method. Use the ReceiveBufferSize property to set this size. If your application will be receiving bulk data, you should pass the Read method a very large application buffer.

If the network buffer is smaller than the amount of data you request in the Read method, you will not be able to retrieve the desired amount of data in one read operation. This incurs the overhead of additional calls to the Read method."

and then read about [NetworkStream.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

At which point you will have a better idea of the complexity of the answer to your question.

Comment: still not clear that when i am fetching 100 records or more using data reader then how many data can be accommodate or stored in network buffer just after one db trip.

Comment: TcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize will give me raw size and from the raw size how can i understand that how many records can be stored in network buffer.

Comment: Surely it's an extrapolation of record size / record data size / tcp overhead. According to Microsoft the default ReceiveBufferSize is 2^13 or 8192 or 8kbytes.