# Any way to see incoming buffer/records from SQL Server?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, performance, concurrency

Basically I have a bunch of performance analysis that [given naive interpetation] claims 70% of the time is spent in synchronization on our web application under heavy load, and mostly in SNIReadSyncOverAsync which internally in the data reader calls. (SNIReadSyncOverAsync actually ends up sitting on a kernalbase.dll!WaitForSingleObjectEx) It would be informative to see if these waits are caller initiated or callee initiated.

Is there a way to see (interpret) this in a Visual Studio Contention or Concurrency Report? Or some other way?

More importantly for my understanding, is there a way to see the incoming buffer that holds data before the data get's consumed by the data reader?

Comment: Perhaps this is not what you are looking for, but are you aware that using [SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190378.aspx) you can view all requests happening on a sql server instance?

Comment: Yes. :) Profiler is awesome. This question is half curiosity, half pragmatism. I'm interested in what is occurring client side in the buffer as the data is received from SQL server. From a practical note, I'm trying to figure out if the application is keeping the client-side (I/O?) buffer relatively empty or if it fills. If SQL Profiler can provide application specific client stats it may work, but I am unaware of this capability if it exists. If it does it solves my problem, but I'd still like to know the above out of curiosity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems my question was ill-informed.

> The datareader reads a record at a time, but it reads it from the
>   underlying database driver. The database driver reads data from the
>   database in blocks, typically using a buffer that is 8 kilobytes.
>
> If your result records are small and you don't get very many, they
>   will all fit in the buffer, and the database driver will be able to
>   feed them all to the data reader without having to ask the database
>   for more data.
>
> If you fetch a result that is larger than the buffer, you will only be
>   able to read the first part of it and when there will no data exist in
>   network buffer then datareader will inform sql server to send next
>   block of data.

[How much data can be stored in network buffer when datareader is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22554158/how-much-data-can-be-stored-in-network-buffer-when-datareader-is-used)