# What happens when my LINQ query gets database records as Enumerable and accesses records in a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, foreach, linq-to-entities

I have a code like this:

```
public class Database : System.Data.Entity.DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}

var db = new Database();
var persons = db.Persons.Where(...).AsEnumerable();
foreach(var person in persons)
{
    //...
}
```

Which of the following scenarios is correct?

- Application fetches entire records from `Persons` table by one request to database, then access each record from memory.
- In each step of `foreach` loop, application fetches only one record from database .

Comment: Your `db.Persons.Where(...)` will generate a sql query and will execute the where statement server side. The rows will be streamed to you client. (do **not** use `.ToList()` or any etc,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Which of the following scenarios is correct?
>
> - Application fetches entire records from Persons table by one request to database, then access each record from memory.
> - In each step of foreach loop, application fetches only one record from database.

None of these statements is entirely correct. But first, let me say that in your code `.AsEnumerable()` doesn't actually do anything. You can remove it without changing anything logically. `IQueryable` implements `IEnumerable` and [`foreach` executes `IEnumerable` methods under the hood](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx). So it addresses `IQueryable` "as enumerable".

Now for the reading part. From the application's point of view, the second statement is closest to the truth. It receives all entities in `persons` one-by-one. It's not before the end of the loop that all `persons` have been made available.

But the actual lower-level reading happens in chunks. As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22554158/861716), the client stores raw data from the database in network buffers. Depending on the size of these buffers and that of the result set (i.e. the number and size of `persons`) it *is* possible that all records are read at once. "Large" amounts of data will require multiple reads.

For the application, that doesn't really matter though. When it comes to performance optimization, I think the last thing we should think of is playing with network buffer size. So to reword the second statement more correctly:

- In each step of foreach loop, only one record from the database is sent to the application's scope.

Answer (score 2):

The first scenario is correct; the application will fetch the recordset from the Persons table matching your where clauses using a single request to the database, then access each record from memory.

Ofcourse, "under the hood" it's a bit more complicated than that. However, while the application might receive the records one-by-one, only a single query is executed on the database - as seen by the profiler screenshot below.

`AsEnumerable` does not execute the query as `AsEnumerable` preserves deferred execution and just casts your collection to an IEnumerable.

The query will be executed at the start of the loop, as that's where you'll request the data.

```
foreach(var person in persons) // <- query executes here
{
    //...
}
```

An easy way to test this is by hooking up a SQL Server Profiler and check the query being executed on the database:

[image: SQL Server profiler]

As you can see only a single query is executed.

In case the objects in your collection contain child objects, it'll execute queries to fetch those, since by default EF is lazy-loading the resultset.

Adding `.ToList()` will force query execution slightly earlier:

`var persons = db.Persons.Where(...).ToList();`

Comment: Did you mean all data will be fetched from DB at the start of the loop and then this application accesses each record from a collection in memory?

Comment: All `person` objects will be in-memory, although it might execute additional queries within the loop if you access any child objects of `person` (since it's lazy-loading by default).

Comment: @OmidEbrahimi I've updated my answer and added a screenshot to explain what happens.

Comment: Ultimately it really depends on how the IQueryProvider implements GetEnumerator and IEnumerator. In Entity Framework though the above answer is correct.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful, but I think @Gert-Arnold's answer is closer to the intended purpose. Thanks very much

Comment: @OmidEbrahimi Well, he kind of gave the opposite answer to mine. My answer assumes you're using Entity Framework.

Comment: @Nicholas It seems his answer is true for Entity Framework, too. I tested it by adding `db.Database.Connection.Close();` inside the `foreach` loop and an error was thrown. The error message is _Calling 'Read' when the data reader is closed is not a valid operation.._ It means application tried to access database and read data from database after first iteration (Query executed in first iteration as we see in your screenshot but application reads data from database piece by piece and it doesn't fetch entire records from database).

Comment: @OmidEbrahimi my screenshot is taken after the loop finished. Obviously EF keeps the connection open until it finishes the operation and you dispose your DBContext. EF doesn't know if it needs to load more data, while the loop is still going (see my lazy loading comment).

Comment: @Nicholas, By lazy loading, application doesn't execute any `Read` until we access some child objects of `person`. But in mentioned test in my previous comment I don't access any child of person.
In the another test I replaced `persons` with `persons.ToArray()` and I don't get any error by closing connection inside the `foreach` loop.It means when we enumerate on the `IEnumerable persons`, application  doesn't fetch entire records and execute a database `Read` in each iteration and it seems the second scenario in my question is closest to what happens under the hood.

Comment: It looks like I'm misunderstanding you, but that ok. The best way to test this yourself is by hooking up a SQL Server Profiler.